Would an object floating on a very low dense object go away by the force of air resistance?
Suppose that you have an object that is floating on the surface of a fluid. If the fluids viscosity was low enough, would normal air have enough drag to make it go away flying?
If it would, how would you calculate the air drag needed in terms of the objects mass and the fluids viscosity?
Thanks to everyone!

That depends solely on the geometry and mass of the object. It is definetely possible for a light object with appropriate shape to be blown off the surface of (say, for example) water by a strong gust of wind. The minimum force required to do this would be the weight of the object plus the adhesive force between the object and the fluid.
